# Compiles only when \newcommand section is inlined

Tags: macros

I'm trying to run the following

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Margins Packages %%
\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}

%% Graphics Packages %%
\usepackage{tikz}

%% Timeline Packages %%
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

%% Graphics Path %%
\graphicspath{{../Pictures/}}

%% Custom Commands %%
\newcommand\circularpicture[7]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[
        circle, 
        draw=#1, 
        line width=#2, 
        inner sep=#3, 
        path picture={
            \node at (#4, #5) {
                \includegraphics[width=#6]{#7}
            };
        }] (A) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\fcolorbox{black}{black}{
        \begin{minipage}[]{0.40\textwidth}
            \textcolor{white}{
                \begin{center}
                    \fontsize{25pt}{20pt}\selectfont Name\\
                    \fontsize{15pt}{20pt}\selectfont Subject                    \\
                    \vspace*{20.0pt}
                \circularpicture{white, 1mm, 1.2cm, 0, -0.8cm, 5cm, cover-picture}
                \end{center}
            }
        \end{minipage}
    }
\end{document}
```

but I obtain the below errors.

```
line 45: Paragraph ended before \@textcolor was complete. }
line 45: Argument of \circularpicture has an extra }. }
line 45: Paragraph ended before \circularpicture was complete. }
line 45: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. }
```

However if I substitute the command into the document directly it compiles fine.

```
\documentclass{article}

%% Margins Packages %%
\usepackage[margin=0cm]{geometry}

%% Graphics Packages %%
\usepackage{tikz}

%% Timeline Packages %%
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

%% Graphics Path %%
\graphicspath{{../Pictures/}}

\begin{document}
    \noindent\fcolorbox{black}{black}{
        \begin{minipage}[]{0.40\textwidth}
            \textcolor{white}{
                \begin{center}
                    \fontsize{25pt}{20pt}\selectfont Ivor Denham-Dyson\\
                    \fontsize{15pt}{20pt}\selectfont Data Science and Software
                    \\
                    \vspace*{20.0pt}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                        \node[
                        circle, 
                        draw=white, 
                        line width=1mm, 
                        inner sep=1.2cm, 
                        path picture={
                            \node at (0cm, -0.8cm) {
                                \includegraphics[width=5cm]{cover-picture}
                            };
                        }] (A) {};
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                \end{center}
            }
        \end{minipage}
    }
\end{document}
```

I'm new to commands and not sure why?

Comment: Your macro wants seven arguments and you're supplying just one. Arguments must be braced, not issued as a comma separated list.

Comment: Does the trick thank you. Still in coding mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do

```
\newcommand{\foo}[7]{...}
```

TeX expects calls such as

```
\foo{one}{two}{three}{four}{five}{six}{seven}
```

and not

```
\foo{one,two,three,four,five,six,seven}
```

Here's a new version of your code, which is also streamlined and has various fixes:

1. `%` characters are used to mask the endlines which would produce an unwanted space in output;
2. `fix-cm` has been loaded to enable any font size;
3. `\fontsize` has a suitabe baselineskip value to better control spacing;
4. Instead of an overall `\textcolor{white}{...}` it's simpler to declare white at the beginning of the `\fcolorbox` content;
5. Instead of `center`, it's better to declare `\centering`.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}

%% Graphics Packages %%
\usepackage{tikz}

%% Timeline Packages %%
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

%% Custom Commands %%
\newcommand\circularpicture[7]{% <--- don't forget
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[
        circle, 
        draw=#1, 
        line width=#2, 
        inner sep=#3, 
        path picture={
            \node at (#4, #5) {
                \includegraphics[width=#6]{#7}
            };
        }] (A) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}% <--- don't forget
}

\begin{document}

\fcolorbox{black}{black}{% <--- don't forget
  \color{white}% <--- don't forget
  \begin{minipage}[]{0.40\textwidth}
  \centering
  \fontsize{25pt}{32pt}\selectfont Name\\
  \fontsize{15pt}{18pt}\selectfont Subject\\
  \vspace*{20pt}
  \circularpicture{white}{1mm}{1.2cm}{0}{-0.8cm}{5cm}{example-image}
  \end{minipage}% <--- don't forget
}

\end{document}
```

[image]